# Failed to call function "on click" in magento 2

Tags: template, magento2.2.2, custom-button

I have created the add button using the below block file.
On button click, I have called return FilterControl.addItem() from my template file seo.phtml But it shows errors like below

> Uncaught ReferenceError: FilterControl is not defined
> at HTMLButtonElement.onclick

Please provide me with a solution

**Note : I have referred core template**  **Magento/Catalog/view/adminhtml/templates/catalog/product/edit/price/tier.phtml**

**Block.php**
<?php

```
namespace xx\yy\Block\Adminhtml\News\Edit\Tab;

use xx\yy\Model\SeoPageFactory;

class File extends \Magento\Backend\Block\Widget implements
\Magento\Framework\Data\Form\Element\Renderer\RendererInterface
{

    protected $_seopage;
    protected $_attributeFactory;
    protected $_template = 'xx_yy::seo.phtml';

    public function __construct(\Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context $context, SeoPageFactory $seopage, \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Attribute\CollectionFactory $attributeFactory, array $data = array())
    {
        $this->_seopage = $seopage;
        $this->_attributeFactory = $attributeFactory;
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
    }

    protected function _prepareLayout()
    {
        $button = $this->addChild(
                'add_button', \Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Button::class, ['label' => __('Add Filter'), 'click' => 'return FilterControl.addItem()',
            'class' => 'add']
        );
        $button->setName('add_filter_button');
        $this->setChild('add_button', $button);
        return parent::_prepareLayout();
    }

    public function render(\Magento\Framework\Data\Form\Element\AbstractElement $element)
    {
        $this->_element = $element;

        $this->setElement($element);
        return $this->toHtml();
    }

    public function getAttributes()
    {
        $collection = $this->_attributeFactory->create()->addVisibleFilter()->addIsFilterableFilter();
        return $collection;
    }

    public function getFilters()
    {
        $pageId = $this->getRequest()->getParam('id');
        if ($pageId) {
            $page = $this->_seopage->create()->load($pageId);
            return $page->getFilters();
        }
    }

    public function getAddButtonHtml()
    {
        return $this->getChildHtml('add_button');
    }

}
```

**seo.phtml**

```
<?php $_htmlId = $this->getElement()->getHtmlId();
?>
<?php $_htmlClass = $this->getElement()->getClass() ?>
<?php $_htmlName = $this->getElement()->getName() ?>
<div class="admin__control-table-wrapper">
    <table>
        <tr id="attribute-options-table">
            <td class="label"><?php echo $this->getElement()->getLabel() ?></td>
            <td colspan="10" class="data-grid">
                <table  class="admin__control-table" cellspacing="0"  id="filters_table">
                    <col width="120" />
                    <col width="120" />
                    <col width="1" />
                    <thead >
                        <tr id="attribute-options-table">
                            <th class = "col-default control-table-actions-th"><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('Attributes') ?></th>
                            <th class = "col-default control-table-actions-th"><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('Options') ?></th>

                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody id="<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $_htmlId ?>_container"></tbody>
                   <!--<tbody id="container"></tbody>-->
                    <tfoot>
                        <tr>
                            <td></td>
                            <td colspan="4" class="a-right"><?= $block->getAddButtonHtml() ?></td>
                        </tr>
                    </tfoot>
                </table>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>

    <script>
        require([
            'mage/template',
            "prototype",
            "mage/adminhtml/form"
        ], function ($, mageTemplate) {

            // var filterRowTemplate = '<p>hi</p>';

            alert("asgsedg");
            var FilterControl = {

                addItem: function () {
                    alert("test");
                }
            };




        });


    </script>
</div>
```

Comment: FilterControl is not mention in template file. Look at group price or tier price template .

Comment: File Path: Folder_name/vendor\magento\module-catalog\view\adminhtml\templates\catalog\product\edit\price\tier.phtml

Comment: use xx\yy\Model\SeoPageFactory; how you extend model class from Block parent class ????

Comment: Reference : Block Tier 
namespace Magento\Catalog\Block\Adminhtml\Product\Edit\Tab\Price\Tier

Answer (score 0):

in your Block.php File

please replace code :

```
protected function _prepareLayout()
    {
        $button = $this->addChild(
                'add_button', \Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Button::class, ['label' => __('Add Filter'), 'click' => 'return FilterControl.addItem()',
            'class' => 'add']
        );
        $button->setName('add_filter_button');
        $this->setChild('add_button', $button);
        return parent::_prepareLayout();
    }
```

**TO**

```
protected function _prepareLayout()
    {
        $button = $this->addChild(
                'add_button', \Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Button::class, ['label' => __('Add Filter'), 'onClick' => 'return FilterControl.addItem()',
            'class' => 'add']
        );
        $button->setName('add_filter_button');
        $this->setChild('add_button', $button);
        return parent::_prepareLayout();
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, for the response but it is not working